# How to solve a permission error when running TabPy in Powershell Prompt

Tags: python, tabpy

It says to enter "tabpy" to run the server, but when I try to in the Anaconda Powershell Prompt it gives me a permission error:

`(base) PS C:\> tabpy`

...

`return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)`

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\tabpy_log.log'`

Comment: Have you tried running powershell as administrator?